# How to add attack speed using commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In version 1.9, the combat section of the update added a cooldown timer. My problem lies with the fact that some Minecraft maps have no cooldown, and replace it with attack speed (attack speed increases the cooldown).
So what command adds attack speed to tools?

Comment: One way to accomplish this is to have command blocks that detect if a player is holding a certain item, and if so, give them haste.  One thing I'm not sure about without looking is if haste also increases attack speed of weapons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use item attributes. I've seen this approach on a few maps.

Using the command

```
/give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.attackSpeed",Name:"generic.attackSpeed",Amount:1000,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:1,UUIDMost:1}]}
```

You can give yourself a diamond sword with the maximum attack speed on it. This eliminates the cooldown of attacks.

(PS: you can find more about attributes on the wiki, [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Attribute))

Comment: Ok, thx for the cmmand (and the wiki)!