# How do you modify the attack speed NBT in Minecraft 1.16?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was trying to modify a tool's attack speed NBT, and stumbled across [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/298335/how-to-add-attack-speed-using-commands) thread. I tried to use the command, but it only seems to reduce the actual attack damage of the tool, and not the attack speed. Is there an updated way to increase the attack speed of a tool effectively, and without reducing the damage dealt?

Comment: I assume you did, but did you format the command correctly for 1.13+? `/give <target> <item>{<properties>} <count>`? I assume you did if you got it to even go through but should probably check just in case

Comment: @Penguin yup, the item showed that there were 2 nbt tags on it, but the attack speed didn't change. the damage was decreased to 1

Comment: What was the exact command you ran?

Comment: @randomuser922 the command was `/give @p diamond_sword{AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.attackSpeed",Name:"generic.attackSpeed",Amount:1000,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:1,UUIDMost:1}]}`. Did this work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command was generated from [MCStacker](https://mcstacker.net) using the `give` command generator.

```
/give @p diamond_sword{AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.attack_speed",Name:"generic.attack_speed",Amount:1000,Operation:0,UUID:[I;-756158760,-1248440979,-1426007026,1776833309],Slot:"mainhand"}]} 1
```

This command worked for me.  As for your command, it seems that Minecraft requires a `UUID` for attribute modifiers, instead of a `UUIDLeast` and `UUIDMost`.

Comment: while this command does seem to increase the attack speed, it also decreases the attack damage. how would you prevent this from happening?

Comment: @12rhombiingridwnocorners what does it say for the attack damage?  Default is 7 for diamond sword.  It shouldn't do anything to attack damage.  It works as intended for me(attack speed it up, and attack damage isn't touched).

Comment: sorry for the late response, it didn't list the attack damage, only saying '+1000 Attack Speed'. Is there a way to preserve the 7 attack damage, or do you need to add it explicitly in the command? 
it's strange that it doesn't affect your attack damage. are you playing on 1.16.5?